# How to restrict users from viewing builds in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Some of our users should not be able to see build information in Artifactory, how to restrict those users from accessing builds in Artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Group and add to it the desired users by following the [Managing Users Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Users#ManagingUsers-CreatingandEditingGroups).

Create a new Permission Target with desired permissions (while not allowing viewing builds) by following the [Managing Permissions Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions), and add the Group you create to this target.